# Localize DropDownList

Tags: winforms, drop-down-menu, localization, telerik

How can I localize the Telerik DropDownList items in C# WinForms ?

All other controls can be localized when I change the main window language, but the DropDownList have only one set of items for all languages in resource.

Comment: Somewhere during load you need to check your culture or other settings that tells your user's locality and set the drop down to the list of items you prepared to that locality

Answer (score 0):

You should localize the item's text according to your requirement. There is no built in translator to do this for you.